# How to maintain the same socket connection on two different pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, express, socket.io

I am creating a page to play a card game, this is for several players who can connect to different rooms. I am having problems in the lobby, where you can see which players are connected to a room. It happens that using the sockets I call the io() function in a section, this connection that is generated is used to connect the client to a room when requested, as I need to use the connection (socket) in another section, I import it with javascript, but this makes me call the io() function again and create a new connection and this is not connected to the room that I had already specified.

This is my code of one of the client parts:

```
const socket = io();

$("#createParty").click(() => {
  const code = newCode();
  socket.emit("client: newParty", {userName: sessionStorage.getItem("userName"), code: code});
  window.location.href = "/room";
});

$("#connectParty").click(() => {
  const codeConnect = $("#txt-codeConnect").val();
  socket.emit("client: tryConnectParty", {userName: sessionStorage.getItem("userName"), codeConnect: codeConnect});
  window.location.href = "/room";
});

export default socket;
```

There are two buttons, one that creates the room or party and another one that connects you to one of them, both emit different events to the server.

Here is my server side code:

```
// Import for server...
import { Server as WebSocketServer } from "socket.io";
import http from "http";
import app from "./app.js";

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new WebSocketServer(server);

var rooms = [];
export var usersRoom = [];

// Events socket...
io.on("connection", (socket) => { 
  console.log("New conection:", socket.id);

  socket.on("client: newParty", (data) => { // data = {userName, code} 
    const code = data.code; 

    socket.join("room-"+ code);  
    rooms.push(
      { 
        room: code, 
        users: [
          data.userName
        ]
      }
    ); 
  });

  socket.on("client: tryConnectParty", (data) => { // data = {userName, codeConnect} 
    const code = data.codeConnect;
    for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
      if (rooms[i].room == code) {
        const userName = data.userName;
        const room = "room-"+ code; 
        socket.join(room);
        rooms[i].users.push(userName);
        usersRoom = rooms[i].users;
        socket.to(room).emit("server: newConnection", userName);
      }
    }
  });
});

export default server;
```

I use a variable called rooms, that is composed by the existing rooms and the users connected in it, this is so that the new player that connects can see all the players already connected, the problem is for the players that were already connected at the moment that a new one enters.

As you can see the server receives the two different events, in the event "tryConnectParty" the server checks if the code of the room is in the rooms variable, when it finds it, it emits an event to that room.

This is my code from another part of the client:

```
import socket from "/main.js";

const userName = sessionStorage.getItem("userName");
$("#txt-userName").html(`<b class='text-white'>${userName}</b>`);
$("#txt-codeRoom").html(`<b>${sessionStorage.getItem("code")}</b>`);

var divPlayers = $("#players");

socket.on("server: newConnection", (userName) => {
  divPlayers.append(createCard(userName));
});

function createCard(user) {
  return `
      <div class="card d-inline-flex text-center" style="width: 300px;">
          <div class="card-body">
          <span class="h1 text-dark">${user}</span>
          </div>
          <img class="card-img-bottom" src="img/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
      </div>
    `;
}
```

This javascript code is called by a html one:

```
<script src="/logic/players.js" type="module"> </script>
```

This is the "room" section, here you can receive the "newConnection" event that creates a card with the name of the new user so that the user can see the new player.

The event "newConnection" never arrives or is received. I was checking several times the code and it was when I realized that when the "socket" is imported is when the io() function is called again and the connection is lost, as this is a new connection and the event is only sent to those who are in the room.

I want to know if there is a better way to do it or how I could solve this, since I can't move forward without this.

Comment: `when the io() function is called again and the connection is lost` yes, that means it can't connect. Are you sure your server even started? IIRC you need to `server.listen(PORT)` on the backend

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the server is started, otherwise it would not receive the tryNewConnection or newParty events.